# Regular Expression matching doesn't work

Tags: c#, regex

Hi all I am pretty new to regex world I am trying to match this regex

```
"\bAsm_vidEmfUpdate_2 (0, ?unknown?)\b"
```

with this string `"Asm_vidEmfUpdate_2 (0, ?unknown?)"`.

I tried to inject '\' before characters '(' , ')' , '?' , ',' to be like this

`"\bAsm_vidEmfUpdate_2 \(0\, \?unknown\?\)\b"`
 but it doesn't work either

But it results in unmatching here is my code

```
string regexStr = "\bAsm_vidEmfUpdate_2 \(0\, \?unknown\?\)\b";

Regex regex = new Regex(regexStr);

string instr = "Asm_vidEmfUpdate_2 (0, ?unknown?)";
MatchCollection m = regex.Matches(instr); 
string str1 = m[0].Groups[0].Value; // ArgumentOutOfRangeException
```

Comment: problem is not with your regex..

Comment: @JonSkeet Edited: sorry for that it is a function that injects '\' before characters '(' , ')' , '?' , ','

Comment: Using regex to match literal string is adding unnecessary overhead.

Comment: Recommend using this tool to understand what happens: https://www.debuggex.com/

Comment: It's still really not clear what you're trying to achieve. Where did you get that regex from? If that's meant to be the original regex, then the `(0, ?unknown?)` part is grouping, although it looks like it's trying to provide a name in an odd way. We're lacking a *lot* of context here.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `Groups[1]` but you're not capturing one. Change the regex to the below or use `Group[0]` which is the entire match.

```
string regexStr = "(Asm_vidEmfUpdate_2 \(0, \?unknown\?\))";
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it's *matching* correctly but you only have a single group (the whole string). So `Groups[1]` is invalid - if you ask for `Groups[0]` it's fine:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string regexStr = @"Asm_vidEmfUpdate_2 \(0\, \?unknown\?\)";
        Regex regex = new Regex(regexStr);

        string instr = "Asm_vidEmfUpdate_2 (0, ?unknown?)";
        MatchCollection m = regex.Matches(instr); 
        string str1 = m[0].Groups[0].Value;
        Console.WriteLine(str1);
    }
}
```

It's unclear what you're trying to achieve though. Your regex doesn't allow for any flexibility, so you're *effectively* just asking for `string.Contains`. If you're trying to capture the different parts of the string, you might want something like:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string regexStr = @"([A-Za-z_0-9]+) \((\d+), ([^\)]+)\)";
        Regex regex = new Regex(regexStr);

        string instr = "Asm_vidEmfUpdate_2 (0, ?unknown?)";
        Match m = regex.Matches(instr)[0];
        foreach (Group group in m.Groups)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(group.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Asm_vidEmfUpdate_2 (0, ?unknown?)
Asm_vidEmfUpdate_2
0
?unknown?
```

(Note that group 0 is still the whole string...)

Comment: @AvinashRaj: No, I know. I was using the OP's regular expression without changing it, to show that that isn't the issue.

Comment: If I use '\b' to match whole words it doesn't match

Comment: @IbrahimAmer: That comment doesn't give nearly enough information. We don't know where you're using `\b`, or what the input is.

Comment: I want my regular expression to be like 
"\bAsm_vidEmfUpdate_2 \\(0, \?unknown\?\)\b"
when I use this it doesn't match

Comment: @IbrahimAmer: Well that doesn't match what's currently in the question, does it? Are the question marks and brackets meant to be escaped or not? (Even the brackets have changed in this comment since I first replied to it!) Every time you change what you're asking, it's wasting the time of the people trying to help you. *Please* put some effort into making your question clear. It's intensely frustrating to answer the question that's been asked, only to find out it's not the *real* question after all.